# given a list, only go through it once, find out how many numbers in that list. And print reversely the number in the list + count

Tags: algorithm, list

given a list contains only number, only go through it once (that means, once a number is being read, it disappears). find out how many numbers in that list. And print reversely the number in the list + count.
For example,   1 2 3 5 -> 9 7 6 5;

Comment: I didn't quite understand how 1 2 3 5 gives output as 9 7 6 5

Comment: Please elaborate ur question

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @zenwraight `count` is 4, so 5+4 is 9, 3+4 is 7, ...

Comment: Setup some kind of `List`, `ArrayList` for example. Iterate it reversely, access the current element and add `list.size()`. Print that value, done.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Dumping your homework with no attempt is outside the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm for the above question:-

```
1. Create a new empty list or vector, let's call it ansList.
2. As you are iterating over your current list, push new elements i.e item + count to your ansList.
3. Reverse your ansList.
4. Print your list.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: he wont get the count before finishing the list

Answer (score 0):

1. create a stack S of ints and also a int variable C initialized with 0
2. iterate the list until end and insert each element in S. also increment C for each element
3. pop N from top of the stack S until S is empty and print N + C